# VBA Using RefEdit to copy cells and removing duplicates

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

Good day to everyone reading.

I have a problem with regards to removing duplicates, when I use the RefEdit function to copy selected cells. I can easily copy using RefEdit without removing duplicates following code:

```
Private Sub cmdKopier_Click()
Dim selrange As Range
Dim addr As String
addr = RefEdit1.Value
Set selrange = Range(addr)
selrange.Copy Destination:=activecell
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

but to remove any duplicates, I have tried using the AdvancedFilter function, but I haven't quite been able to make it work. Any suggetions are appreciated. :)
Note, it has to be copied to an acitvecell or a selected cell, and not a specific range (for example C2:C10 or something), as it will be used in different workbooks in different columns. Thanks again!